# Microsoft Bot + Cortana in Windows 10 Laptop

Tags: bots, botframework, cortana, cortana-skills-kit

I am facing a strange issue, Cortana app in Android phone invoking my bot perfectly fine.

But the same is not working in Windows 10 laptop though I have logged in using the same Microsoft Id that I used to develop the bot and also laptop region and language set to United States and English(United States).

Please help me out.

Comment: "not working" is not very descriptive. Provide more info about what exactly is not working. Have you done some investigations in order to determine what/where is broken?

Comment: Thanks Pawel for your reply.  Basically I say the same invoke phrase in Windows 10 laptop that I am saying in Android phone but its redirecting me to Bing results.  Any specific settings needs to be cross verified in the laptop?

Comment: Are you logged into Cortana with the same email address you used to register your bot on dev.botframework.com?

Comment: Please report this issue at https://github.com/microsoft/botbuilder/issues/new so we can better assist you

Comment: I've been able to work around this by not delaying before the invoke statement. "Hey Cortana ask my chatbot to ..." - one statement no pauses.

Comment: Thank you everyone!   Issue was with my company laptop (firewall and all).